# RemoteViews is not saving correctly to bitmap with getDrawingCache

Tags: android, image, view, bitmap, remoteview

I want to draw the Notification contentview, which is a RemoteViews, into a bitmap.

I'm using this code:

```
private Bitmap getImageOfRemoteViews(RemoteViews rv) {
  try {
        View view = rv.apply(mContext, null);
        view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap screenshot = view.getDrawingCache(true);
        return screenshot;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

the View is build into the bitmap but not the whole view, there is the right part missing.

As it should be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEndu.jpg

As it is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C2hz.jpg

By manually setting the layout like:

```
view.layout(0, 0, 720, 250);
```

only the background color is added but not the 2 textviews (here: "1:12" and "Info")

Do someone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: It'd be great if this worked!

Comment: how do you even got this^ to work? I only get my views inflated, but with no values (TextViews are empty, AnalogClock always at 12.00). Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @gilm Any solution to this? without hardcoding the width and height!

Comment: @pedram nothing new since that old post :(